# В чем отличие между init-method и factory-method в Spring?

Tags: spring

В чем отличие между init-method и factory-method  в Spring при создании бина в xml контексте Spring?

Comment: Дубликат вашего вопроса [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18772490/what-is-the-difference-between-spring-factory-method-and-factory-bean).

Comment: @IgorKonyaev В моем понимании, по ссылке указана разница между init-factory и factory bean. Factory bean это то же самое что и init-method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`init-method` - это возможность явного задания метода для **пост-инициализации** бина. Является аналогом [InitializingBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html). Для `init-method` существует противоположность в виде `destroy-method` или [DisposableBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/DisposableBean.html), т.е. **пре-деструктор**.

`factory-method` - это метода вызываемый для **создания** бина. Может быть статическим методом класса, указанного в атрибуте `class`, или методом другого бина, указанного в атрибуте `factory-bean`.

Чтобы более подробно пояснить ситуацию скажу, что у каждого **бина есть жизненный цикл**. В контексте данного вопроса мы можем представить жизненный цикл как:

1. Создание бина (при помощи прямого вызова конструктора, или `facory-method`'а, или иными способами);
2. Внедрение зависимостей в бин;
3. Пост-инициализация (вызов `init-method` или использование других возможностей пост-инициализации);
4. Использование бина (т.е. пока жив контекст в котором это бин определён);
5. Уничтожение бина (вызов `destroy-method` или использование других возможностей пре-деструкторизации).

Исходя из вышесказанного `factory-method` и `init-method` используются для разных потребностей, потому нет смысла приводить их различия. `factory-method` используют для ручного управления созданием бина, а `init-method` можно использовать, к примеру, для проверки, что все поля инициализированы корректно.